# Is "venting" halal, or even sunnah?

Tags: halal-haram, behavior

[Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/vent) defines "vent" in a few ways: *a verbalized frustration* or *to express a strong emotion*.  [Google](https://www.google.com/#q=vent) describes it as:

> ...give free expression to (a strong emotion).

These emotions or frustrations can be about various things, e.g. inability to find a partner, a neighbour's loudness, customer dissatisfaction, and so on.

Some people vent as a means of working through problems, and so on.  It has both [positives and negatives](https://www.psychologytoday.com/blog/evolution-the-self/201404/6-virtues-and-6-vices-venting) from a mental health standpoint.  Generally, it's good to communicate about one's problems, but done too harshly or to the wrong person may backfire.

**Question**: Is "venting" halal, or even sunnah?

I'm wondering if this behaviour is appropriate, or even encouraged in Islam.

Answer (score 1):

Islam has only very few rules as what is haram. Venting, taking out frustration etc is definitely not the sunnah of our dear prophet sallallahu alaihi waslam but also not haram. 
When prophet was angry, his cheek would turn red and people knew he was angry. But he never vent or abused any living soul, verbally or physically.

I do not remember whether I read it in hadeeth or was told to say, 'subhan'Allah' in case of frustration or angry on others/our-own mistakes.